# How to read XML config file in java

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
 <config>
   <seperator>
     <entry key ="fileSeprator">|</entry>
        </seperator>
        <columncount>
            <entry key ="colcount">4</entry>
        </columncount>
        <columnName>
            <entry key ="0">ClientID</entry>
            <entry key ="1">ID</entry>
            <entry key ="2">FirstName</entry>
            <entry key ="3">LastName</entry>
        </columnName>
        <exception>
            <entry key ="0">ClientID_Blank_Null</entry>
            <entry key ="1">ID_Blank_Null_incorrect</entry>
            <entry key ="2">FName_IS_Null</entry>
            <entry key ="3">LName_IS_Null</entry>
        </exception>
        </config>
 </properties>
```

//I have above xml property file. How to read in java code. Here Key =0 is the Position in the file. File do not have Column Name, but position is fix.I just want how to read this in Java code. And if value is blank then put the exception from the property file. Just help me to read this file in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, when you click the different button, it will show the different checkbox.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Checkbox;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DynamicCheckBox extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel north;
    private JPanel center;

    public DynamicCheckBox() {
        north = new JPanel();
        JButton first = new JButton("First");
        JButton second = new JButton("Second");
        north.add(first);
        north.add(second);
        center = new JPanel();
        center.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 100, 20));
        first.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                center.removeAll();
                Checkbox[] box = createCheckBox(new String[]{"1", "2"});
                for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
                    center.add(box[i]);
                }
                center.repaint();
                DynamicCheckBox.this.revalidate();
            }

        });
        second.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                center.removeAll();
                Checkbox[] box = createCheckBox(new String[]{"3", "4"});
                for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
                    center.add(box[i]);
                }
                center.repaint();
                DynamicCheckBox.this.revalidate();
            }

        });
        this.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DynamicCheckBox();
    }

    public Checkbox[] createCheckBox(String[] values) {
         Checkbox[] box = new Checkbox[values.length];
         for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
             box[i] = new Checkbox(values[i]);
         }
         return box;
    }
}
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: Thank you, I compiled this code and working but here my question is "I have a text with some script name for the Frame 1 Frame 2 etc. it may have 10 script name or in future 200. I have to read each script / test name and show it with check box. Also one other problem is  how to align the frame as shown in the prototype

Comment: You can read all script name and store it in a String array and pass it to the method `createCheckbox()`, the method will return an array of checkbox. For the layout, I think you can use titleBorder and GridLayout to achieve the align

Comment: Yes I did try that but the layout is creating problem, as its dynamic. Can you give me some code that will generate similar prototype at least for one Test Frame please?